# Please How to build and train a tensorflow Model to reconize the wakeword "red on" and "red off". I want to control a LED

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

**How to build and train a tensorflow Model to reconize the wakeword "red on" and "red off". I want to control a LED**

Comment: You do not need a tensorflow model for this.

Comment: can you help me? What do I need for this? As a requirement The model has to be a KI model that's why I mentioned tensorflow.

Comment: Why is it a requirement? Is it an assignment or something? You could (and should) do a simple string comparison if it is not.

Comment: In fact, I'm writing my thesis and the project is about speech recognition on a microcontroller (Arduino more precisely) using the tinyML. The required steps are to build a ML Model using Tensorflow, to train it and then to convert it into a Tensorflow Lite Model and to depolyment it on the microcontroller

Comment: Hi! You can use speech recognition through Tflite. Attaching relevant threads for reference. https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/tiny-ml-team8/tiny-ml-team8-arduino-nano-33-ble-wake-word-detection-0ad9b8     https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/a_g_v/voiceturn-voice-controlled-turn-lights-for-a-safer-ride-3a8e78                          
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/msb4180/speech-recognition-and-synthesis-with-arduino-2f0363